# Elements not processing event when Material-ui Popup is displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, material-ui, dom-events

I have a simple material-ui `List` containing `ListItem` elements.

I want a `Popover` to appear beside whatever `ListItem` I place the mouse over. For this I am using the `mouseEnter` event. In its handler I set the **anchor element** of the `Popover` to be the `ListItem` that the mouse pointer is currently over.

This works fine for the first element which I hover over. However because the `Popover` is essentially behaving in a "modal" type fashion, when I move to another `ListItem` in the List its `mouseEnter` event doesn't get fired.

I've been at this for a few hours now and can't find a way around it ?

Here's a CodeSandbox. Try hovering on one of the `ListItem`s and you'll see output in the console. Try moving to another and nothing happens.

[image: Edit loving-currying-zpw8y]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { List, ListItem, ListItemText, Popover } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [popoverAnchorElement, setPopoverAnchorElement] = useState(null);
  const handleMouseEnter = event => {
    console.log("onMouseEnter - " + event.currentTarget.textContent);
    setPopoverAnchorElement(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, index) => {
    setPopoverAnchorElement(null);
  };

  let isPopoverOpen = Boolean(popoverAnchorElement);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List style={{ maxWidth: "100px" }}>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}>ListItem1</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}>ListItem2</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}>ListItem3</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <Popover
        open={isPopoverOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorEl={popoverAnchorElement}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText>ListItemInPopover</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Popover` component overlays the whole screen (`position:fixed; left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; z-index:1300`), effectively blocking any mouse events from lower items.

You could try to circumvent this, for instance adding `pointer-events:none;` to its overlay element would allow cursor events to pass through it.

But, using a component that blocks the whole viewport just for a small menu item seems odd to me and is likely an uphill battle.

There is a similar component in the same library called `Popper`, which probably is more suited to your needs. Here you can see I've converted your `Popover` to a `Popper` and you get results a little more like what you're expecting. (Note I added some CSS to this element in the code sandbox to make it clearer.)

```
  <Popper
    open={isPopoverOpen}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorEl={popoverAnchorElement}
    className="popper-item"
  >
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemText>ListItemInPopover</ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
  </Popper>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-smoke-x8tu7

I will note that the documentation points out that `Popper` will not automatically close if you click away from these items, but that this can be added.

You might also look into the `MenuList` component which uses `Popper` under the hood but also handles some state for you.